# Is "If we'd all work together" past or future tense?

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

> If we'd all work together, I think we could accomplish our goal

What tense is it? Past or future?

- The goal has been failed because they didn't work together*, or*
- They will have a chance to accomplish them goal if they work together.

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence, we'd is an abbreviation for **we would**, expressing possibility.

[would](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) modal verb (POSSIBILITY) (also 'd) used to refer to a ​situation that you can ​imagine ​happening:

> If we **would** all work together, I think we could accomplish our goal

So, your second explanation is correct:

> I imagine that we will have a chance to accomplish our goal if we all work together.

Comment: If the contraction _we'd_ stood for _we had_ instead of _we would_, though, the first interpretation would be correct. However, were that the case, much of rest of the sentence would need to be modified: _If we'd all work**ed** together, I think we could **have** accomplish our goal_.

Comment: @J.R., agreed. **Accomplish** would also have to become a past participle, though.

Answer (score 2):

This conditional deals with “unreal, but likely” situations in the present or future. We call it “unreal” because situation we are describing hasn’t happened yet, and “likely” because we can easily imagine it happening.

1. it hasn’t happened yet (it’s unreal)
2. you believe it could happen (it’s likely)